# Java MySQL returns only one row

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this code:

```
try {
    Integer user = InformationService.authenticate(username, password, connection);
    Statement st = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE uid = " + user + " ORDER BY title ASC");
    System.out.println("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE uid = " + user + " ORDER BY title ASC");
    while (rs.next()) {
        Task p = new Task(rs.getString("title"), rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("descriere"),
                rs.getString("data"), rs.getInt("uid"), rs.getString("data_creare"), rs.getString("ora"),
                rs.getInt("status"), rs.getString("priority"), rs.getInt("sters"), rs.getInt("id_parinte"),
                rs.getInt("notify"), rs.getString("assigner"), rs.getInt("durata"), rs.getInt("project_id"));
        System.out.println(p);
        tasks.add(p);
    }
```

The problem is that it returns only the first row, and if I run the query manually I get more results (16 total). Here's the output:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE uid = 4 ORDER BY title ASC
models.Task@164b9b8f
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: what is the count of results that you get while running manually, Would appreciate if you paste some data

Comment: generally we keep uid unique

Comment: @JqueryLearner the problem is that it's not returning all the rows.

Comment: Are the databases same when you ran manually and through your code? I mean, are you connecting to the same database and server in both cases?

Comment: Yes, the databases are the same. There should be 16 entries

Comment: @Sherlock have you checked like this *SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE uid = 4 ORDER BY title ASC* in mysql ?

Comment: May be the `tasks.add(p)` is causing exception and you are not catching to trace it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can improve the code a bit like below which will help you to quickly identify the issue.

```
int rowCount = 0;

try {
    Integer user = InformationService.authenticate(username, password, connection);
    Statement st = connection.createStatement();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE uid = " + user + " ORDER BY title ASC";
    System.out.println(query);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
        Task p = new Task(rs.getString("title"), rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("descriere"),
            rs.getString("data"), rs.getInt("uid"), rs.getString("data_creare"), rs.getString("ora"),
            rs.getInt("status"), rs.getString("priority"), rs.getInt("sters"), rs.getInt("id_parinte"),
            rs.getInt("notify"), rs.getString("assigner"), rs.getInt("durata"), rs.getInt("project_id"));

        rowCount++;
        System.out.println(rowCount + "." + p);
        tasks.add(p);
    }
} finally {
    System.out.println("Number of records = " + rowCount);
}
```

In this approach you can clearly identify how many rows were iterated.

Comment: thanks. actually this helped me find that i was not printing e.printStackTrace() in my catches. :)